# Custom UIView with tapGesture

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a drawing app. Inside my VC there are five imageViews with five colors in them. I want to be able to click on the imageView and change the stroke color. It can be easily done if I repeat myself in the viewcontroller by adding gesture Recognizers to each UIImageView and have their individual "selector" function. Such as

```
func redTapped() {}
func blueTapped() {}
```

However, I want to be able to make the code more clear by creating a custom class (ColorImageView.Swift) for these ImageViews so that when I assign the class to these buttons, they automatically gets the tap gesture and my VC automatically receives the information about which one is tapped. At the moment, I can get a "imagePressed" printed out for each image that gets assigned to my class. However, I have no  way of distinguishing which one were pressed. Below are my code for ColorImageView.Swift

```
import Foundation

class ColorImageView: UIImageView {

    private func initialize() {
        let touchGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ColorImageView.imagePressed(_:)))
        touchGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.addGestureRecognizer(touchGesture)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initialize()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        initialize()
    }

    func imagePressed(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("image pressed \(gestureRecognizer)")
    }
}
```

My imageView names are red.png, green.png, blue.png...etc

Thanks

[image: editVC]

Comment: Please show your ViewController coding I mean which you added ColorImageView to ViewController

Comment: I dont have any code for my VC yet. I want to be able to first distinguish which imageView were tapped from the custom class. Than once that is completed, I can use protocol to pass information to my VC. At the moment I can get print out like the following when I pressed the imageView.....

Image pressed <UITapGestureRecognizer: 0x7fd323749a20; state = Ended; view = <ProjectName.ColorImageView 0x7fd323748dc0>; target= <(action=imagePressed:, target=<ProjectName.ColorImageView 0x7fd323748dc0>)>>

Comment: Where did you set the images?

Comment: my images are located inside my EditImageViewController with IBOutletes declared inside the VC. Attached is a screenshot of the VC

    IBOutlet weak var redImageView: ColorImageView!

Comment: Please show that attached screen shot

Comment: @user3182143 Attached. Sorry I was uploading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121252/discussion-between-edward-hung-and-user3182143).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the tag easily.It works fine.

```
func imagePressed(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
   print("image pressed \(gestureRecognizer)")
   let tappedImageVIew = gestureRecognizer.view as! UIImageView
   print("image pressed \(tappedImageVIew.tag)")
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Much much appreciated